# Can drum lessons be applied to mallet percussion instruments?

Tags: drums, mallet-percussion

I recently got a glockenspiel for fun. I'm a beginner when it comes to percussion. I'm wondering if I can see it as a drum, and watch drum lessons or should I only look at lessons that are specific for mallet percussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glock is much, much closer to a keyboard than it is to drums. The fact that it needs beaters or hammers (or mallets) to produce sound is as close as it gets. there are many different ways in which to hit drums, producing different sounds, which don't apply to glocks, or xylophones, or even vibes for that matter.

Instead, consider the mallets to be extensions of your arms/handsfingers, used in order to make the instrument sound. The only real relationship is that both drums and glocks need to be hit to produce sound. Plus, if it's a one or two octave glock, the movements in comparison to playing a drumkit are also quite foreign.

Comment: I found things like a roll (aka tremolo) on the glock is completely specific to it and doesnt exist on the piano. ie the muscles you develop from doing it. I'm sure there are other things too. but I found the roll to be the most important so far.

Answer (score 1):

Learning drum rudiments would definitely apply to playing glockenspiel. There are many drum techniques that apply to mallet instruments as well, such as marching/field drum techniques.

That said, there are rock drum kit techniques that are not related, such as how to hit cymbals, hi-hat and kick techniques, and other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to need drum rudiments - the rolls, paradiddles, flams etc. that drummers spend time on.  And you're not going to have to be the time-keeper of a band.

If you get yourself into a band, worry about technique when it's required by the music they give you.  Until then, just pick some tunes out.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of it as a percussion instrument.  One that requires mallets you'll want to spend time on developing proper hand and mallet technique. Notes same like a drum but certainly not the rhythmic foundation of the ensemble.  Your timing and control would improve by learning and practicing some snare drum rudiments or exercises(not for musicality, but a great idea to add to your practice regime.

This is because when you learn the notes/scales etc. they must be played with good timing and clean, sometimes at fast tempos too. As a 20 year drummer and percussionist myself I'd recommend you try incorporating certain rudimental snare drum exercises into your practice routine.  Your overall technique and rhythmic timing would certainly benefit.